# Compare duplicate certs in an array and delete matches with the oldest expirations dates

Tags: arrays, bash, macos, date, certificate

Im working on a new script to manage duplicate certificates in macOS.

The one remaining unsolved task I am involves these steps:

1 Parse the macOS system keychain, get all certs that match the name "my_certificate". I have this working as shown below

2 If there is only 1 cert named "my_certificate" then exit 0. No duplicates to worry about.

3 If there is more than 1 cert named "my_certificate" (i.e.; dupes exist), then compare all the expiration dates and sort accordingly.

4 Keep only the most recent certificate and delete any duplicates with older expiration dates. I have the code to delete a cert based on its SHA-1 hash.

I have all the Mac-specific logic of how to interact with the System Keychain (parsing, deleting etc - this is something I do all the time).

I already have the logic to delete EXPIRED certificates (which runs earlier in this script but not shown in my example and thus only valid duplicates remain to be processed).

```
            #!/bin/sh
            
            IFS=","
                
                CERT_LIST=$( security find-certificate -a -c "my_certificate" -p -Z "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain" | sed s/"-----END CERTIFICATE-----"/"-----END CERTIFICATE-----,"/g)
                
                if [[ -n "${CERT_LIST}" ]]; then
                    
                    CERT_ARRAY=(${CERT_LIST})
                    
                    for CERT_ELEMENT in "${CERT_ARRAY[@]}"; do
                            
                        CERT_EXPIRATION_DATE_FULL=$( openssl x509 -noout -enddate <<< "${CERT_ELEMENT}" | cut -f2 -d= )
                        CERT_EXPIRATION_DATE_FORMATTED=$( date -j -f "%b %d %T %Y %Z" "${CERT_EXPIRATION_DATE_FULL}" "+%Y-%m-%d" )
                        CERT_EXPIRATION_DATE_FORMATTED_TRUNCATED=$( echo ${CERT_EXPIRATION_DATE_FORMATTED} | tr -d "-" )        
                        CERT_SHA1_HASH=$( grep -e 'SHA-1 hash:' <<< "${CERT_ELEMENT}" | cut -d" "  -f3- )
                        CERT_ARRAY_INDEX_NUMBER=$((${CERT_ARRAY_INDEX_NUMBER}+1))
                
                        echo "QA testing: Certificate (${CERT_ARRAY_INDEX_NUMBER}): Hash: ${CERT_SHA1_HASH} Expiration date: ${CERT_EXPIRATION_DATE_FORMATTED_TRUNCATED}"
                
                        
    #I'm stuck HERE
    # at the process of examining the remaining duplicate certs, 
    # and determining which cert is the 'newest' one to keep.
    # I have all the cert data I need at this point.
        
        
                    done
                    
                else
                    
                    echo "Error: Certificate "my_certificate" could not be found."
                    exit 1
                    
                fi
exit 0
```

An example of my QA data looks like this in stdout (for testing):

Certificate (1): Hash: C65CC29A9EDFCB6AA00A3FC0E64ED32084624A56 Expiration date: 20220503

Certificate (2): Hash: B0C2D933C09E29DCA09F4EB8099B4D11F6DE3E86 Expiration date: 20220507

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an array `certs` holds the `cert data`, which will be achieved
by relacing the `echo "QA testing: Certificate..` line in the for loop with:

```
certs+=("echo "QA testing: Certificate..")
```

Then please try:

```
# the assignment below is just for demo and they should be assigned in the loop
certs=(
  'QA testing: Certificate (1): Hash: C65CC29A9EDFCB6AA00A3FC0E64ED32084624A56 Expiration date: 20220503'
  'QA testing: Certificate (2): Hash: B0C2D933C09E29DCA09F4EB8099B4D11F6DE3E86 Expiration date: 20220507')

# put the code below after the loop "for CERT_ELEMENT in "${CERT_ARRAY[@]}"; do .. done"
mapfile -t certs_sorted < <(printf "%s\n" "${certs[@]}" | awk '{print $NF, $0}' | sort -nrk1,1 | sed 's/^[0-9]* //')
```

Now `"${certs_sorted[0]}"` holds the latest certificate and
`"${certs_sorted[@]:1}"` hold the older ones.

By convention, it is recommended to use lower cases for user's variable names.

**[Edit]**
If `mapfile` is not available, replace the `mapfile` line with the following:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    certs_sorted+=("$line")
done < <(printf "%s\n" "${certs[@]}" | awk '{print $NF, $0}' | sort -nrk1,1 | sed 's/^[0-9]* //')
```

which assigns the array `certs_sorted` to the sorted certificates as well.
If the process substitution `<(command)` is not available, here is an alternative:

```
lines=$(printf "%s\n" "${certs[@]}" | awk '{print $NF, $0}' | sort -nrk1,1 | sed 's/^[0-9]* //')
while IFS= read -r line; do
    certs_sorted+=("$line")
done <<< "$lines"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Unfortunately, the mapfile utility is not available in my distribution of macOS and I cant find it on any of the open source repositories (homebrew, etc)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've update my answer with an alternative. Would you please try it? BR.